# ANDROID: weird getMaximumRange() function result

Tags: android, android-sensors

When I use function **getMaximumRange()** to get maximum value of the accelerometer I get curiously large number: **10320**. The maximum value I managed to get is ≈ 19.59. 
Can you please tell me what number is this **10320**? It's not maximum value of accelerometer for sure.

I only get this value on the **HTC EVO 3D**.
On **HTC Wildfire** it's proper maximum value.